# C# - Adding UserControl in different thread causes exception even after invoking

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, user-controls

I built a custom UserControl in WinForms and to add it to a Panel through a secondary thread.

I know that when adding control through secondary thread you need to invoke the main thread to do it. So i did.. but i still get an exception saying "Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'pictureBoxImage' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on."

I'm stuck and don't know what is causing this because i tried debugging it by placing a break point on each of my custom UserControl methods but the exception is not thrown by any of them.

```
private void addControl(Control i_ControllToAdd, Control i_ParentControl)
    {
        if (i_ParentControl.InvokeRequired)
        {
            i_ParentControl.Invoke(new Action(() => addControl(i_ControllToAdd, i_ParentControl)));
            return;
        }

        i_ParentControl.Controls.Add(i_ControllToAdd);
    }
```

and this is the custom UserControl class

```
public partial class FBPostUserControl : UserControl
    {
        private readonly string m_UserName = string.Empty;
        private readonly Image m_UserProfileImage = null;
        private readonly DateTime? m_DatePosted = null;
        private Image m_Image = null;
        private string m_PostBody = string.Empty;

    public string UserName
    {
        get { return m_UserName; }
    }

    public DateTime? DatePosted
    {
        get { return m_DatePosted; }
    }

    public Image Image
    {
        get { return m_Image; }
        set
        {
            if (value == null)
            {
                pictureBoxImage.Visible = false;
            }
            else
            {
                pictureBoxImage.Visible = true;
                pictureBoxImage.Image = value;
                updateImageSize();
            }
        }
    }

    private void updateImageSize()
    {
        if (pictureBoxImage.Image != null)
        {
            double ratio = pictureBoxImage.Image.Width / pictureBoxImage.Image.Height;
            pictureBoxImage.Height = (int)(pictureBoxImage.Width / ratio);
            pictureBoxImage.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
        }
    }

    public string PostBody
    {
        get { return m_PostBody; }
        set
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value) == false)
            {
                labelPostBody.Visible = true;
                labelPostBody.Text = value;
            }
            else
            {
                labelPostBody.Visible = false;
            }
        }
    }

    public Image UserProfileImage
    {
        get { return m_UserProfileImage; }
    }

    public FBPostUserControl(string i_Name, Image i_ProfileImage, DateTime? i_PostDate)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        m_UserName = i_Name;
        m_UserProfileImage = i_ProfileImage;
        m_DatePosted = i_PostDate;

        refreshHeader();
    }

    private void refreshHeader()
    {
        pictureBoxUserImage.Image = m_UserProfileImage;
        labelName.Text = m_UserName;

        if (labelDate != null)
        {
            labelDate.Text = m_DatePosted.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            labelDate.Visible = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any Control should be created on UI thread and **also accessed from the same thread.**

The reason it's giving you exception because you are creating your `ControlToAdd` on one thread(your secondary thread) and adding it to UI on another thread(your UI thread) by using Invoke statement.

To get rid of this, make sure you create control on one thread and access it on the same thread its created on.

Following snippet may not be what you want but it's just to give you an idea about it;

```
i_ParentControl.Invoke(new Action(() => addControl(new Control(), i_ParentControl)));
```